# Xrandr not recognizing '-HSync' as an option

Tags: fedora, xrandr

This is the command I'm trying to run

```
sudo xrandr --newmode Modeline "5120x2880_60.00"  1276.50  5120 5560 6128 7136  2880 2883 2888 2982 -hsync +vsync
```

However, whatever I do, I always get this output

```
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hsync'                  
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
```

So I check out the help and as it turns out xrandr expects -HSync and -VSync instead of -hsync and -vsync. I tried with these replaced and still got the same result. Also tried running as root with no luck. Someone on the arch forums had a similar issue which he solved by rebooting. I've tried that as well without any luck.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the "Modeline" part:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "5120x2880_60.00"  1276.50  5120 5560 6128 7136  2880 2883 2888 2982 -hsync +vsync
```